# Nice read / Nice reading

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

When you read a book and you want to express your excitement, what do you say:

**"it was a nice read"**

OR

**"What a nice read"**

OR

**"Nice reading"**

OR

There's something else which is most suitable?
I know that I could simply say: "I enjoyed reading this book" but I remember seeing a lot of people using the word "nice" but don't exactly remember how it was constructed though.

Comment: Check this *[post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46735/is-a-very-good-read-grammatically-correct)* in our sibling community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that "*it was a **good** read*" is a more idiomatic way of saying a book was enjoyable, at least in BrEng. Still, "a nice read" also sounds fine.

"Nice read*ing*" sounds more like a compliment on someone's reading ability, as "reading" is the *action* or *skill* of reading. It is what teachers write on children's reports when they have read well out loud - "Nice reading!"

However, in some contexts a passage of text that is intended to be read out loud can also be referred to as "*a* reading", and so it would not be completely out of place to say "*that was an enjoyable reading*" in reference to the text itself.

For general use though, I would stick with "good read", or "nice read" if that is idiomatic in the place where you live.